# How can I assign a common template for ember components

Tags: ember.js

I have several components and each of them have a template all the same, how can I assign a common template for ember components?

Comment: In that case, why you have several components ? You can have one component. right ? Could you please provide jsbin with your code what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Umm, by specifying the same template name?

Comment: @Susai It does seem weird, but I'm willing to accept that there could be situations where two components which are different in terms of their logic might somehow usefully share the same template.

Comment: I just in the situation torazaburo said, I have several components that different in logic and each of them template content is {{yield}}, I don't know whether the way I package componet is right, but now I want to assign a common template for all compontents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have common templates between components i would probably do one of the following,

1. Inherit one component from the other, or from a base one to extend the `layoutName` property

example1: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jewohekiwu/1/edit?html,js

2. Use a common `partial` helper

example2: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/helefevome/1/edit?html,js

also an article with inheritance no layoutName property and a common partial http://blog.yanted.com/2014/01/17/inheritance-with-ember-js-components/

**example1**
**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{my-comp1 testProp="lala"}}
    <br/>
    {{!other-name-for-comp2 testProp="lolo2"}}
    {{my-comp2 testProp="lolo"}}
  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/my-comp1">
  comp1 - testProp:{{testProp}}
  </script>
```

**js**

```
App.MyComp1Component = Em.Component.extend({
  layoutName:"components/my-comp1",
  test:function(){console.log("comp1");console.log(this.get("testProp"));}.on("init")
});


App.MyComp2Component = App.MyComp1Component.extend({
  test:function(){console.log("comp2");console.log(this.get("testProp"));}.on("init")
});

//Em.Handlebars.helper("other-name-for-comp2", App.MyComp2Component);
```

**example2**
**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{my-comp1 testProp="lala"}}
    <br/>
    {{my-comp2 testProp="lolo"}}
  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/my-comp1">
 {{partial "_commonTemplate"}}
  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/my-comp2">
  {{partial "_commonTemplate"}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_commonTemplate">
   comp1 - testProp:{{testProp}}
  </script>
```

**js**

```
App.MyComp1Component = Em.Component.extend({
  test:function(){console.log("comp1");console.log(this.get("testProp"));}.on("init")
});


App.MyComp2Component = Em.Component.extend({
  test:function(){console.log("comp2");console.log(this.get("testProp"));}.on("init")
});
```

Comment: The first way is work for me. But my components is mutually independent, so I specify a common template for every componet by layoutName attribute in js file.